# Distinction between inline and display math instead of default behavior of texmathp

Tags: latex, auctex, texmathp

The default behavior of `texmathp` gives true regardless of wheter the cursor is inside an inline or display math environment.

Is there a way for `texmathp` to display true only if the cursor is inside an inline math environment or only inside a display math environment ?

Comment: @Gabriele Nicolardi: Tag [texmathp] does seem appropriate. (I mistakenly thought it was just a predicate, but it also performs side effects.) Perhaps you'd like to fill out its tag description? ;-)

Comment: @Drew I filled the tag description (I just copied the definition of the function and a small description from `texmathp.el`). I would like it to also provide functions to use as isearch-filter-predicate. I already have my own, tested and working. Now I would like to add the ability to distinguish between inline math and displaymath. What do you think about this idea?

Comment: No idea. The last time I used LaTex was in the late 80s. ;-) If you want `texmathp.el` to be enhanced then I suggest you send your request/patch to its maintainers. And thanks for doing it.

Answer (score 2):

`C-h f texmathp` says:

```
Determine if point is inside (La)TeX math mode.
Returns t or nil.  Additional info is placed into ‘texmathp-why’.
The function assumes that you have (almost) syntactically correct (La)TeX in
the buffer.
See the variable ‘texmathp-tex-commands’ about which commands are checked.
```

and `C-h v texmathp-why` says:

```
After a call to ‘texmathp’ this variable shows why math-mode is on or off.
The value is a cons cell (MATCH . POSITION).
MATCH is a string like a car of an entry in ‘texmathp-tex-commands’, for
example "equation" or "\ensuremath" or "\[" or "$".
POSITION is the buffer position of the match.  If there was no match,
it points to the limit used for searches, usually two paragraphs up.
```

So you can write a function that calls `texmathp` and, if that returns `t`, examines the value of `texmathp-why` to figure out whether it's an inline or display:

```el
(defun my/texmathp ()
   (if (texmathp)
       (cond 
        ((string= (car texmathp-why) "$") "inline")
        ((string= (car texmathp-why) "\\(") "inline")
        ((string= (car texmathp-why) "$$") "display")
        ((string= (car texmathp-why) "\\[") "display")
        (t (car texmathp-why)))))
```

This returns a string (or `nil` if there is no math environment): `"inline"` for `$...$` and `\(...\)`, `"display"` for `$$...$$` and `\[...\]` and something else for other cases (e.g. `"equation"` for `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` etc).

Adjust to taste.

EDIT: Here's a simplified version using `pcase` instead of `cond`:

```el
(defun my/texmathp ()
   (if (texmathp)
       (pcase (car texmathp-why)
         ((or "$" "\\(") "inline")
         ((or "$$" "\\[") "display")
         (t (car texmathp-why)))))
```

EDIT (in response to some of the OP's comments below): Org mode uses `org--math-p` as a `before` advice on `texmathp`. You can rewrite that function to be more discriminating, so that it distinguishes `\(...\)` or `$...$` environments from `\[...\]` or `$$...$$` environments. But that's a different question from what you asked, so you should ask it as a new question. Note that there is no mention of Org mode in your question or in the tags (please don't change the question now - ask a new one).

Comment: I deleted my answer because yours made me realize I was wrong. It had never occurred to me to use `textmath-why`. I'll definitely keep that in mind.

Comment: Thank you this looks quite good. When the major is org mode, texmathp-why gives "Org mode embedded math" regardless of wheter the cursor is in inline math like \\( ...here...\\) or display math like \\[... here ...\\] . That said, I do not plan to use \\[ and will instead use \begin{environment here} environments without surrounding \\[ and \\]. There might be a lot of extra cases with \begin{environment here} . For example with \begin{align}, texmathp-why gives "align".

Comment: I will adapt it to my needs but overall the most important for others that might want to use this is that it might not work in org mode if they use \\[ and \\] for display math instead of \begin{... environment here ...} \end{... environment here ...}

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi This solution might not be ideal for org mode, what method did you consider ?

Comment: @userrandrand I don't use or know Org mode, and I don't think I can suggest anything better than the solution proposed by NickD if you want to use `texmathp`. Alternatively, you could define predicates yourself, perhaps to be used in combination with `texmathp`.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi I am not sure what you mean by defining predicates. Would that involve writing a parser that detects the enviroment that the cursor is in ?

Comment: If your problem is only with `\[...\]` you could write a function to test if point is inside these delimiters, You could integrate in the NickD solution. But, as I said, I don't know Org mode.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi as for Org mode, I am new to writing latex in emacs but the advantages seem to be that one can execute code within the document which could be easier for adding some figures and tables rather than going to a separate buffer or software and org mode is planning on releasing some live rendering of latex as I understand with asynchronous rendering of latex preview images and automatic switching from latex preview to latex editing when the cursor is in or out of a math environiment like (I have not tried the following, and do not know if it is safe to use) org-fragtog but faster

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Thank you, the \\[ ... \\] mention is more for future visitors of this page. I do not use it, I use \begin with math enviroments but future visitors might consider writing something for that case

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi As I understand the video in the following link gives some examples of future features in org mode but I think the live latex rendering is not shown there although I have not seen it yet https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nA9YzooqpWY

Comment: That video describes a feature that John Kitchin added (and has made available publicly) but AFAIK there is no plan to integrate that into Org mode.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi note that the variable is called `texmathp-why`.

Comment: `There might be a lot of extra cases with \begin{environment here} . For example with \begin{align}, texmathp-why gives "align".` - most of them are display.  Only `$...$`, `\(...\)`, `\begin{math}....\end{math}` and `\ensuremath{...}`  are inline, so you can check for these four and declare everything else `display`.

Comment: @NickD Concerninig the video, are you saying there is no plan to integrate that in org mode because it was rejected ? Because the github page of the functionality shown says that it is expected that the functionality will be included into the next release of org mode https://github.com/karthink/org-preview .

Comment: The video is about "Justifying orgmode LaTeX fragment overlays" - not sure how it is connected with the org-preview git repo.

Comment: The video was made 7 years ago, so the functionality it shows has nothing to do with `org-preview-mode`: it uses the old Org LaTeX preview.

Comment: @NickD My apologies, I am not sure how that happened, That is not the link I was supposed to share. I was supposed to share https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-AfvuV-bYo

Comment: Great demo! Thanks for sharing.